# Cannot show this svg icon

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I have this svg icon, but does not show up at all on the page.
I need to make it bigger 50x50 px, what am I doing wrong here.

```html
<svg width="50px" height="50px" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" data-radium="true"><path fill="red" d="M505.403 406.394L295.389 58.102c-8.274-13.721-23.367-22.245-39.39-22.245s-31.116 8.524-39.391 22.246L6.595 406.394c-8.551 14.182-8.804 31.95-.661 46.37 8.145 14.42 23.491 23.378 40.051 23.378h420.028c16.56 0 31.907-8.958 40.052-23.379 8.143-14.421 7.89-32.189-.662-46.369zm-28.364 29.978a12.684 12.684 0 0 1-11.026 6.436H45.985a12.68 12.68 0 0 1-11.025-6.435 12.683 12.683 0 0 1 .181-12.765L245.156 75.316A12.732 12.732 0 0 1 256 69.192c4.41 0 8.565 2.347 10.843 6.124l210.013 348.292a12.677 12.677 0 0 1 .183 12.764z"></path><path fill="red" d="M256.154 173.005c-12.68 0-22.576 6.804-22.576 18.866 0 36.802 4.329 89.686 4.329 126.489.001 9.587 8.352 13.607 18.248 13.607 7.422 0 17.937-4.02 17.937-13.607 0-36.802 4.329-89.686 4.329-126.489 0-12.061-10.205-18.866-22.267-18.866zM256.465 353.306c-13.607 0-23.814 10.824-23.814 23.814 0 12.68 10.206 23.814 23.814 23.814 12.68 0 23.505-11.134 23.505-23.814 0-12.99-10.826-23.814-23.505-23.814z"></path></svg>
```

Comment: To start with you haven't set a `viewbox`

Comment: it should work even without it as optional.... no? thanks for comment

Comment: well it's optional BUT you need to pay attention the size of your path ... add a big width and height and you will see your icon without viewbox but this is not the result you will need ... so as @Paulie_D said, it's mandatory in this case

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are missing the viewbox

```html
<svg width="50px" height="50px"  viewBox="0 0 510 510" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" data-radium="true"><path fill="red" d="M505.403 406.394L295.389 58.102c-8.274-13.721-23.367-22.245-39.39-22.245s-31.116 8.524-39.391 22.246L6.595 406.394c-8.551 14.182-8.804 31.95-.661 46.37 8.145 14.42 23.491 23.378 40.051 23.378h420.028c16.56 0 31.907-8.958 40.052-23.379 8.143-14.421 7.89-32.189-.662-46.369zm-28.364 29.978a12.684 12.684 0 0 1-11.026 6.436H45.985a12.68 12.68 0 0 1-11.025-6.435 12.683 12.683 0 0 1 .181-12.765L245.156 75.316A12.732 12.732 0 0 1 256 69.192c4.41 0 8.565 2.347 10.843 6.124l210.013 348.292a12.677 12.677 0 0 1 .183 12.764z"></path><path fill="red" d="M256.154 173.005c-12.68 0-22.576 6.804-22.576 18.866 0 36.802 4.329 89.686 4.329 126.489.001 9.587 8.352 13.607 18.248 13.607 7.422 0 17.937-4.02 17.937-13.607 0-36.802 4.329-89.686 4.329-126.489 0-12.061-10.205-18.866-22.267-18.866zM256.465 353.306c-13.607 0-23.814 10.824-23.814 23.814 0 12.68 10.206 23.814 23.814 23.814 12.68 0 23.505-11.134 23.505-23.814 0-12.99-10.826-23.814-23.505-23.814z"></path></svg>
```

Answer (score 3):

Add `viewBox` attribute with real size

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 520 520" width="50px" height="50px" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" data-radium="true"><path fill="red" d="M505.403 406.394L295.389 58.102c-8.274-13.721-23.367-22.245-39.39-22.245s-31.116 8.524-39.391 22.246L6.595 406.394c-8.551 14.182-8.804 31.95-.661 46.37 8.145 14.42 23.491 23.378 40.051 23.378h420.028c16.56 0 31.907-8.958 40.052-23.379 8.143-14.421 7.89-32.189-.662-46.369zm-28.364 29.978a12.684 12.684 0 0 1-11.026 6.436H45.985a12.68 12.68 0 0 1-11.025-6.435 12.683 12.683 0 0 1 .181-12.765L245.156 75.316A12.732 12.732 0 0 1 256 69.192c4.41 0 8.565 2.347 10.843 6.124l210.013 348.292a12.677 12.677 0 0 1 .183 12.764z"></path><path fill="red" d="M256.154 173.005c-12.68 0-22.576 6.804-22.576 18.866 0 36.802 4.329 89.686 4.329 126.489.001 9.587 8.352 13.607 18.248 13.607 7.422 0 17.937-4.02 17.937-13.607 0-36.802 4.329-89.686 4.329-126.489 0-12.061-10.205-18.866-22.267-18.866zM256.465 353.306c-13.607 0-23.814 10.824-23.814 23.814 0 12.68 10.206 23.814 23.814 23.814 12.68 0 23.505-11.134 23.505-23.814 0-12.99-10.826-23.814-23.505-23.814z"></path></svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

define the viewBox

```
<div id="svgContainer">
<!-- This is an HTML div, and inside goes the SVG -->
<svg width="50px" height="50px"  viewBox="0 0 510 510" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" data-radium="true"><path fill="red" d="M505.403 406.394L295.389 58.102c-8.274-13.721-23.367-22.245-39.39-22.245s-31.116 8.524-39.391 22.246L6.595 406.394c-8.551 14.182-8.804 31.95-.661 46.37 8.145 14.42 23.491 23.378 40.051 23.378h420.028c16.56 0 31.907-8.958 40.052-23.379 8.143-14.421 7.89-32.189-.662-46.369zm-28.364 29.978a12.684 12.684 0 0 1-11.026 6.436H45.985a12.68 12.68 0 0 1-11.025-6.435 12.683 12.683 0 0 1 .181-12.765L245.156 75.316A12.732 12.732 0 0 1 256 69.192c4.41 0 8.565 2.347 10.843 6.124l210.013 348.292a12.677 12.677 0 0 1 .183 12.764z"></path><path fill="red" d="M256.154 173.005c-12.68 0-22.576 6.804-22.576 18.866 0 36.802 4.329 89.686 4.329 126.489.001 9.587 8.352 13.607 18.248 13.607 7.422 0 17.937-4.02 17.937-13.607 0-36.802 4.329-89.686 4.329-126.489 0-12.061-10.205-18.866-22.267-18.866zM256.465 353.306c-13.607 0-23.814 10.824-23.814 23.814 0 12.68 10.206 23.814 23.814 23.814 12.68 0 23.505-11.134 23.505-23.814 0-12.99-10.826-23.814-23.505-23.814z"></path></svg>
</div>
```

Javascript :

```
xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET","my.svg",false);

xhr.overrideMimeType("image/svg+xml");
xhr.send("");
document.getElementById("svgContainer")
  .appendChild(xhr.responseXML.documentElement);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/t51y331h/2/